# home folder remap with power shell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I was trying to re-map home drive for all users from DC1 to DC2 but it fails. anyone would notice a mistake in it?

```
$users=Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq "user1"} -SearchBase 'OU=xxx,DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com' -properties * | Where-Object { $_.HomeDirectory -like "*DC1*" } 
ForEach( $user in $users) { 
    $HomeDirectory=$user.HomeDirectory.ToLower()
    $newHomeDirectory=$HomeDirectory.replace("DC1", "DC2")
    Set-AdUser -Identity $user -HomeDirectory $newHomeDirectory
    "$newHomeDirectory set for user $($user.name) ($($user.SamAccountName))"
}
```

I have also tried to remove home drive from DC1 with the following power shell (it did not return any error but did not remove the folder either):

```
$mapped = Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | Select DeviceId, ProviderName
foreach ($item in $mapped) {
    if ($item.ProviderName -eq '\\DC1\users\$env:username') {net use $item.DeviceId /del}
}
```

Comment: Explain "it fails".

Comment: it returns: 'The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scri
pt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'  and You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. char:45

Comment: `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`? Also, what does the question have to do with VBScript?